Dependent attribute value changes are invalid
I have a CustomControl SearchDefalut
There's an IsShowPopup to display Popuo,
Property

        public bool IsShowPopup
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsShowPopupProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsShowPopupProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsShowPopupProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsShowSearch", typeof(bool), typeof(SearchDefalut), new PropertyMetadata(true));



Xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type units:SearchDefalut}">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type units:SearchDefalut}">
                 <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                       BorderBrush="Yellow"
                       BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10">
                     <Grid>
                         <Popup  IsOpen="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Templatedparent}, Path=IsShowPopup}"  AllowsTransparency="True"   StaysOpen="False"
                          Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="200">
                             <Border Background="Gray" Margin="3">
                                 <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                                     <VirtualizingStackPanel x:Name="PART_ItemPanel" Orientation="Vertical" />
                                 </ScrollViewer>
                                 <Border.Effect>
                                     <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="8" ShadowDepth="6" Opacity="0.8" Color="Red" />
                                 </Border.Effect>
                             </Border>
                         </Popup>
                     </Grid>
                 </Border>
                 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                     <Trigger Property="SearchData" Value="">
                         <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="watermark" Value="Visible"/>
                     </Trigger>
                 </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>


The IsOpen of Popup is bound to IsShowPopup. When the program runs, IsOpen renders the effect according to the initial value of the dependent attribute. However, when the control is used to change the value of IsShowPopup, IsOpen cannot be modified, resulting in no PoPup display effect, which makes me very upset
I couldn't achieve it this way either
IsOpen="{Binding IsShowPopu, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type unit:SearchDefalut}},
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"



The dependency property field and the registered dependency property name are not matching: IsShowPopupProperty --> IsShowSearch

"The established naming convention for dependency properties is mandatory for normal behavior of the property system. The name of the identifier field that you create must be the registered name of the property with the suffix Property."

If you follow the practice to name the CLR wrapper property after the dependency property, you can use nameof to avoid typos or renaming errors.

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsShowPopupProperty =             DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsShowPopup), typeof(bool), ...);

oh, my eyes are so bad,
